# Cloudstack: "move volume failed" Error while attaching volume

Tags: disk-volume, cloudstack

I have detached a volume from a VM and now want to attach it to a different VM.

The status notification pop-up says, "move volume failed".

In the events log I see :

```
Description Error while attaching volume. Volume Id: 5447 VmId: 2882
State       Completed
Level       ERROR
Type        VOLUME.ATTACH
```

I happens whether the destination machine is on or off.

The volume's name is DATA-4124.  I able to attach it only to a VM that has the volume ROOT-4124.  I suspected that there was some "affinity" because of similar names, but [the manual](http://cloudstack.apache.org/docs/en-US/Apache_CloudStack/4.2.0/html/Admin_Guide/working-with-volumes.html#detach-move-volumes) is clear that volumes can be moved from one guest VM to another.

What could be the cause of this?

This is in Cloud Stack 4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I have a tentative reply from my Cloud Stack hosting service support desk:

> I am flagging this for [our expert] but, from the top of my head, this might be the case if the destination VM is an older instance from the times storage was arranged differently. We upgraded storage a lot in the meantime but at the cost of compatibility of older instances. If that is the case, you should be able to clone the instance by using the templating feature, but it will not keep the IP if it is not behind a virtual router.
>   If the instance is not older than a couple of months, then I do not know, I leave [our expert] to look into it.